# Add context menu to XBMC-Plugin

Tags: python, xbmc

I am trying to get a context menu to display, where I have a button e.g. to delete (or whatever) the selected item.

Answer (score 2):

On all your `ListItem`s, use addContextMenuItems which takes a list of (label, action) pairs. For action you can use `XBMC.RunScript(somescript.py, someid)` and implement your delete (or whatever) there.

You can check out [XBMC Flicks](https://github.com/spudsdude/XBMC-Flicks) for an example on how to implement something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Simpleplugin framework](http://romanvm.github.io/script.module.simpleplugin/index.html), there is the *context_menu* parameter for [virtual folders](http://romanvm.github.io/script.module.simpleplugin/_actions/vf.html).

Same with [xbmcswift2](https://xbmcswift2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/item.html#context-menu).